# How to get prevState value or all object in useState in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In trek_tours i have an array and inside array i have define object and inside object their are some array and the format is in below

```
treks_tours[  
{
title: "Everest Base Camp",
Prices: [
      "Price Start from 300 per/person",
      "Note - if you are number of people then we can make you good discount!",
],
},{
title: "Jungle Safare & Knowing Villager Life Style",
Prices: [
      "Price Start from 1650 per/person",
      "Note - if you are number of people then we can make you good discount!",
    ],
}
]
```

In this section i want to see the title and price name of differrent objects but i got repeted title same time. anyone please help me!!!

```
const [tripPrice, setTripPrice] = useState({});
const price = () => {
    treks_tours.map((price) =>
      setTripPrice((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        price: price.Prices[0].split(" ")[3],
        title: price.title,
      }))
    );
  };
 console.log(tripPrice);
  useEffect(() => {
    price();
  }, []);
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4LRE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{treks_tours.slice(0, 3).map((trek_tour, key) => {
<p className="text-lg text-black">
Starting from : $ {trek_tour.Prices[0].split(" ")[3]}
</p>
);
})}
```

Comment: Is this correct one?
I'd think your code has a bug.
It should be like the following?

```
{treks_tours.slice(0, 3).map((trek_tour, key) => (
          <p className="text-lg text-black" key={key}>
            Starting from : $ {trek_tour.Prices[0].split(" ")[3]}
          </p>
        ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

So from that array of objects, you want to individually console.log() all of them?

If so you want to individually console.log() all the objects all you have to do is:

```
trek_tours.forEach((tour) => {
  console.log(tour);
})
```

And then it will console.log() every object in array. Is that what you mean?

Comment: can you review again, i have made update

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is setTripPrice to array trek_tours
then all to do is to say `setTripPrice(trek_tours)` - no need of anything else.

Then if you console.log(tripPrice) you get all the objects inside the array. If this is not what you mean please provide a codesandbox link

Comment: so, i want to filter the trip price and show the trip price according to it so at first i want to see trip name and trip price of different price on console.log()